# How to properly create and shutdown a feature

Tags: java, guice

I am working on a feature which can be enabled and disabled by the user.
It is implemented in a separate module and it creates some threads and a few singletons.
Since I have a separate module for it and since we intend to run it later in a separate process, I used a separate guice injector for it.
So I have a factory method that creates the injector and returns a class that implements the feature interfaces (it has 3 interfaces)

```
public class FeatureFactory {
    private Injector injector;
    public FeatureClass open() {
        injector = createInjector();
        return injector.getInstance(FeatureClass.class);
    }
}

public class FeatureClass implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB, InterfaceC {

}
```

Questions:

1. Is it good practice to create a new injector in this case? I mean when the whole feature resides in a separate module?
   The idea was to decouple them and not have the new feature guice module as part of the feature API.If not, What would be a better approach?
2. Returning the feature class instead of the interfaces doesn't smell good.
   It lets the user know about the implementation
   How do I overcome this?
   Currently I used the application guice module to bound the interfaces to the FeatureClass
3. How do I close the feature and have all the classes garbage collected?
   as I said, when the feature is opened, some singletons and threads get created. 
   If I make the injector field null, does that mean that everything get garbage collected?

Comment: Your first question is too broad and primarily opinion-based (as are most best-practice questions) as per the [help/on-topic], please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to create more than one injector. Singletons are scoped in an injector, so when you create multiple injectors, your singletons are no longer singletons.

Instead, create a factory class that allows the caller to create an instance of the class, and inject into that factory a `Provider<FeatureClass>`

```
@Singleton
public class FeatureClassFactory {
  private final Provider<FeatureClass> provider;
  private FeatureClass instance;

  @Inject
  FeatureClassFactory(Provider<FeatureClass> provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  public synchronized FeatureClass get() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = provider.get();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

You could, of course, use a singleton `Provider<FeatureClass>` as your API instead of creating a factory, but 1) I don't like using Guice interfaces in my public APIs and 2) in production mode, singletons are created when the injector is initialized, and you said you wanted to delay creation of `FeatureClass` instances.

As for returning an implementation vs. a class,  which is better is a matter of debate and depends on the use case and your coding style.

Finally, since singletons are scoped with the injector, the injector keeps strong references to all singletons. If you need to release memory during the lifetime of the application, you will have to have your classes free up memory by setting fields to `null` and/or clearing collections.

Comment: Thanks. regarding the creation of a new injector. The reason I wanted to do this is that the whole feature is written in a separate module (a separate jar) so I didn't want a guice module as the jar's api. I wanted to decouple this. Isn't this a valid reason for creating a new injector? I understand of course that the singletons are only singletons in the context of the new injector

Comment: @NirBrachel depends if the user using the jar uses Guice. If they do, a module would be a fine API and creating an injector would be problematic